# How to SELECT rows in an order dictated by a JSONB array of primary key IDs?

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-10

This is my dummy setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE containers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    positions jsonb
);
CREATE TABLE bits (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    container_id integer REFERENCES containers(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    data jsonb
);
```

Example row in `containers`:

```
id  positions
1   [4, 2, 3]
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to use the `positions` in `containers` to dictate the order in which bits are returned. This seems like it might be easier than using a `smallint position` column in `bits` that has values like 0, 1, 2, 3, and must all be updated when the user reorders the bits.

In essence, what I'm trying to do is use the `positions` array in `ORDER BY`, e.g. (pseudo-code):

```sql
SELECT b.id, b.data FROM bits b, container c WHERE b.container_id = 1 ORDER BY (jsonb_array_elements(c.positions));
```

The desired output would be:

```
id  data
4   {"banner": "This is a message!"}
2   {"name": "Bob"}
3   {"playlistId": 3}
```

How do I accomplish this? I'm using Postgres 10.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `jsonb` functions to do this.

Please try something like this:

```
select b.*
  from bits b
       join containers c
         on c.id = b.container_id
       join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(c.positions) 
                      with ordinality as p(id, rn)
         on p.id::int = b.id
 where b.container_id = 1
 order by p.rn::int
```

Comment: This returns the bits in the wrong order (2, 3, 4 - instead of the expected 4, 2, 3).

Comment: Ah, just had to change the `ORDER` clause: `ORDER BY p.rn::int`

Comment: @ffxsam  Sorry about that.  I was thinking that `container_id` should have been the first ordering term.

Comment: Nope, actually the query will use a `WHERE` clause for container id. So this will make a great view where I'll just sort by `p.rn` and then I can pass `WHERE container_id = X` when querying the view.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I made a minor edit to your answer so it fits the question more closely and it's clearer to others.

Comment: @ffxsam  Not at all.  I did not know whether you wanted the `container_id` to group the rows in your output.  That is what led to my first mistake with `b.id`.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help!

Comment: @ffxsam FWIW, the reason there is no easy way to get from a `jsonb` array to a native PostgreSQL array is that json arrays are not typed--they can contain any valid json at each index.